# How we can calculate squared factor loadings in Principal Component Analysis(PCA)?

Tags: spss, pca, rotation

This snapshot is from [THIS](http://www.gcro.ac.za/sites/default/files/reports/occasional_paper_7.pdf) article:

[image]
[image]

What is Squared factor loadings and how we can calculate it. Any link between above snapshot and below snapshot of SPSS output?

[image]

- there isn't any relationship between two snapshots.

Comment: It is **very important** to let people know that the first table is incomplete! Anyone looking at it closely will discover quickly that the column sums do not add up to unity as claimed--but they do sum to unity when the missing rows are included.

Comment: That doesn't help--now you have removed the first part of the table!

Comment: Is table 7 the rotated or unrotated matrix? Is is possible to add it as text so that I can copy it into another program to analyze it?

Comment: @Jeremy Miles .I think as mentioned in PDF it is `Pattern and structure matrix for PCA with varimax rotation`. page 22 of PDF.

Comment: @whuber. Edited again :)

Comment: Thanks, that means it's rotated. (With varimax rotation, pattern and structure are the same).

Comment: The article is ***no more existent at that given link*** (perhaps the given table was found to be in error)